# Why did iAd work well on simulator and device testing, but didn't show up after released on App Store?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iad

I set up iAd by adding `self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;` in ViewDidLoad method. I tested it on simulator and iPhone 4 device. It worked well. But after i released on App Store, iAd didn't show up on the specific view controller. Why is that happened? Thanks!!

Comment: Just go through this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fP2ijcXbCz4). Make sure you did not miss any step!

Answer (score 0):

If your app has been released today or yesterday, it's normal. The ads dont show until a few days after the first release of your app.